# NetBeans remote develop Node.js/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, netbeans, iot

Is it possible setup in NetBeans remote deploy/run, for example same as Java?

**Why:** I develop library for IoT (raspberry, onion.io etc.  all linux based).

**What I need:** I need have possibility to remote run this lib. Develop it in my favorite IDE NetBeans on my PC, then click - RUN and NetBeans should upload it on remote device, and run it on that device. Same stuff is possible if you developing Java, you can setup remote environment for example on Raspberry PI, and by one click run in on Raspberry.

**If it is not possible:** it is here way how automate this process? Upload last version to remote device (SFTP, FTP etc ) and run it remote (SSH?)

Any Idea?